# Is there a way to get document ID of item from FirestoreRecyclerAdapter?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui

I can query Firestore and get IDs manually, but I'm using `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter` because it comes with a ton of additional work done out of the box. So, if I have code like this:

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

Query query = db.collection(COLLECTION_NAME)
        .whereEqualTo("userId", USER_ID)
        .limit(LIMIT);

FirestoreRecyclerOptions options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions
        .Builder<SomeEntity>()
        .setQuery(query, SomeEntity.class)
        .build();

FirestoreRecyclerAdapter adapter = new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<SomeEntity, MyHolder>(options) {
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyHolder holder, int position, SomeEntity model) {
        // I need model ID here
    }
}
```

So, if I use `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter`, it automatically deserializes my `SomeEntity` class into `model` object. This is all fine and dandy, but now I need to attach listeners to the list, and react with model ID. Now, if I was manually deserializing objects from Firestore I'd do something like this:

```
for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
    SomeEntity entity = document.toObject(SomeEntity.class).setId(document.getId());
    list.add(entity);
}
```

But, since `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter` is doing deserialisation for me, I don't get to call `document.getId()` myself. And by the time I'm in `onBindViewHolder` method, I don't have access to document ID anymore. Is there some method I'm missing, some way to retrieve IDs from adapter that I overlooked?

Note, I do not consider redundantly storing IDs as a field a solution. I will rather inherit and override `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter` instead, but I'd prefer if I could solve this without that much work.

Comment: It's sort of silly but I saved the Document ID in the document itself as a field after reading [this comment.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49708212/is-there-a-way-to-get-document-id-of-item-from-firestorerecycleradapter#comment99291713_49708610)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you need the document ID, you should know something already about the item you're dealing with. Typically this will be the position of the item in the list. I.e. when the user clicks on an item, the click handler is passed the ID of that item. If you have the `position`, you can get the `DataSnapshot` from the adapter with:

```
adapter.getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position);
```

So if you want to get the ID, you'd get it with:

```
String id = adapter.getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position).getId();
```

Comment: Thank you, that was the missing piece of the puzzle. I hate this whole NoSql naming convention, it never occurred to me to look for "snapshots" in methods.

Comment: To be honest, I was a bit surprised about that too. In the Realtime Database adapters, it would just be `adapter.getRef(position).getKey()`.

Comment: Concerning pricing, does getting the ID in such a way count as one document read? Thanks

Comment: Yes, reading the ID requires reaching the document, which is a charged operation.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I don't think it reaches server to fetch the Id. As documentation mentions, it gets it from the backing snapshot array (which btw is the result of the query you had provided to adapter)

Answer (score 0):

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener { v ->
            Toast.makeText(v.context, snapshots.getSnapshot(position).id , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        }
```

This comes Under **BindviewHolder**

Answer (score 0):

Use this in OnBindViewHolder

```
String DocID = Objects.requireNonNull (getCurrentList ()).snapshot ().get (position).getId ();
```

If you are using items.class you can create a string with with getter and @DocumentID.

```
private String docID; 

@DocumentId
public String getDocID() {
return docID;
}
```

Then call this in onBindViewHolder

```
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull @NotNull ViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull @NotNull Items model) {
model.getDocId();
}
```