# Delete button on RecyclerView deletes the wrong item

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firestore adapter for my `RecyclerView` and I am having trouble with the 'Delete' button. When I press it, it deletes the wrong item instead of the one that I wanted.

Here is the code for my button inside of the `onBindViewHolder`:

```
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AdminRewardAdapter.RewardViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull RewardModel model) {

    fStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    holder.rank.setText(String.valueOf(position + 1));
    Double dq = model.getDonationReq();
    holder.donationRequired.setText(String.format("%.0f", dq));
    holder.rewardDescription.setText(model.getRewardDesc());

    holder.delete_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            CollectionReference collectionReference = fStore.collection("Rewards");

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext());
            builder.setTitle("Delete");
            builder.setMessage("Are you sure to delete " + (position + 1) + " reward?");
            builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    Query query = collectionReference.whereEqualTo("donationReq", (position + 1));
                    query.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                for(DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()){
                                    document.getReference().delete();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    dialogInterface.dismiss();
                }
            });
            builder.create().show();
        }
    });

}
```

Here is my Firebase if it helps:

[image]

Comment: It means that `document.getReference()` returns a reference to another document. You should use the document ID instead of the position.

Comment: oh the document ID is auto generated in this case..

Comment: Store in a variable and use it later to remove the document.

Comment: You use a position parameter. But the value of this parameter is not the one you expect. Check by logging or toasting in onClick.

Comment: oh my god, it worked! I get what you mean by using variable. 

This is what worked for me: 


Query query = collectionReference.whereEqualTo("rewardDesc", model.getRewardDesc());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete a specific document from the database you'll need to know its ID. So that means when the user clicks on an item to delete, you'll need to be able to look up that item's document ID. For that reason you'll need to get both the values from the document and its ID when you're creating the view.

So in addition to the `RewardModel` objects, you'll also need to keep the corresponding document IDs somewhere.

If you're using FirebaseUI to show the list, you can get the ID for a given position by following: [Is there a way to get document ID of item from FirestoreRecyclerAdapter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49708212/is-there-a-way-to-get-document-id-of-item-from-firestorerecycleradapter)

Answer (score 0):

You are sending wrong data.

```
Query query = collectionReference.whereEqualTo("donationReq", (position + 1));
```

You had write `position` instead of `position + 1`